# Usage of "neither"

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a scientific document and I'm having trouble finding the correct usage for "neither" in a sentence.

The sentence is the following:
"...device which does not require the continuous use of neither a universal testing machine nor a simple load cell."

Which one is more correct, "neither of" or "of neither" in this case? I'm getting pretty confused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keeping with the modern English avoidance of "double negatives", we don't use "neither .. nor" in the scope of an explicit negative "not".

So the normal form of this would be

> device which does not require the continuous use of either a universal testing machine or a simple load cell."

You could say "either of a universal testing machine or of a simple load cell". I can't see any difference in meaning.